Win32: Handling WM_KEY* and respective WM_CHAR pairs together
I have a standard message loop:
MSG msg = {};
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

I'd like to process WM_KEYDOWN and its generated WM_CHAR event together — is this possible? My app first sees if it has a registered keybinding for WM_KEYDOWN, but if not, it should fall through and be interpreted as WM_CHAR.
Due to the separated nature of the queue, I'm not sure how to recognize which message pairs with what. There's no guarantee a WM_KEYDOWN generates a WM_CHAR. A WM_CHAR could also be standalone (e.g., IME input)!
An equally good alternative would be a way to remove the WM_CHAR from the queue in the WM_KEYDOWN body (or just recognize and ignore it).
For example, if the user presses Enter:

WM_KEYDOWN with VK_RETURN is generated.
WM_CHAR with \r is generated.
Say my app processes VK_RETURN. WM_CHAR event should be removed or ignored.

EDIT: A follow-up question: what is the best way to tell if a WM_KEYDOWN has been translated to a WM_CHAR? I see from the documentation that TranslateMessage() "generates a WM_CHAR when the user presses any of the following keys." Do I just hard code that list?

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,10663

@HansPassant Thank you, I get it now! I just need to use PeekMessage() filtering for WM_CHAR and doing PM_REMOVE. Feel free to say this as an answer so I can accept it.

@HansPassant So sorry, I edited a follow-up question about finding out which WM_KEYDOWN messages generate a WM_CHAR.

If you don't want a WM_KEY* message to produce a WM_CHAR message, then don't pass it to TranslateMessage.

@RaymondChen Got it. Would that involve pre-processing the message outside of WindowProc though? It seems like the typical loop translates the message before it even reaches WindowProc.

@Jason1923 yes, you would preprocess it before calling TranslateMessage()
